# Problem with Discrete Parseval's Theorem

Tags: fourier-analysis, signal-processing

I think I must be missing something obvious, but I can't for the life of me see what it is. The discrete version of Parseval's theorem can be written like this:

$\sum_{n=0}^{N-1} |x[n]|^2 = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=0}^{N-1} |X[k]|^2 $

Now, say you've got some function in time, like $x = \sin(\omega t)$. Depending on how large your value of $N$, the LHS could be arbitrarily large.

The FT of this function is a delta function at $\omega$. Everywhere else is zero, so your RHS is given by $1/N$. So how on earth does one side equal the other?! It seems to me like you've got a summation one one side and an average value on the other...

I *must* be missing something obvious!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I completely understand your confusion. It is indeed not so obvious. First of all, you have to be careful which version of Parseval's theorem you are considering. For continuous-time signals or for discrete-time signals, and in the second case for infinitely long signals or for the DFT relation, where only signals of length $N$ are considered. The way you've stated it is the DFT version. This means that the transform of a sampled sinusoid is usually NOT a delta impulse unless the frequency is $2\pi k/N$ (i.e. an integer number of periods fit in the DFT interval of length $N$). If you consider the discrete-time case for infinitely long signals, then neither of the two sums converges in the case of a sinusoidal signal.

**Example:**
$x(n)=\cos\frac{2\pi m}{N}n$ with $0\le m\le N-1$. In this case the DFT
$$X(k)=\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}x(n)e^{-jn\frac{2\pi k}{N}}$$ is indeed given by two discrete deltas:

$$X(k)=\frac{N}{2}\left [ \delta(k-m) + \delta(k+m-N)\right ]$$

Applying Parseval's theorem gives

$$\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}|x(n)|^2=\frac{1}{N}\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}|X(k)|^2=\frac{N}{2}$$

Answer (score 1):

The discrete fourier transform is usually defined as $$
  X_k = \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} x_ne^{-i2\pi \frac{n}{N}k} \text{,}
$$
i.e. *without* a normalizing factor. Now assume a signal is $T$-periodic, and do the transform for $N=T,2T,3T,\ldots$. You get the sequence $X_k,2X_k,3X_k,\ldots$ for the individual $X_k$. In Parseval's theorem, those are *squared* though, so on the RHS *without* the $\frac{1}{N}$ you'd get $R,4R,8R,\ldots$. On the LHS, however, you get $L,2L,3L,\ldots$ since there's no square-of-a-sum involved there, you just square the individual coefficients. For the equality to hold, you thus have to account for this effect, which is where the $\frac{1}{N}$ comes from.

Your argument doesn't hold because by saying "The FT is a delta function" you're glossing over the fact that this $\delta$ is *scaled linearly* as $N$ increases. Squaring makes that quadratic, and multiplying with $\frac{1}{N}$ makes it linear again. Just as the RHS ist.

Comment: The definition of Parseval's theorem in the question is correct and it goes well with the definition of the DFT as you gave it. The problem is that $X_k$ is only a discrete delta for a very restricted set of frequencies.

Comment: @MattL. I didn't say (or imply, I hope) that the theorem was stated wrongly. I explained *why* the $\frac{1}{N}$ is required. To be honest, I don't really buy your argument. Even *one* frequency where this holds is enough for the OP's "counter-argument" to hold. Let $x_n=c$ then $X_k=N\delta_{k,1}$. That's *certainly* a delta function, or, well a *scaled* one. It's precisely the factor $N$ in this $X_k$ that's confusing the OP I think.

Comment: OK. You just emphasized that the DFT is defined without a normalization factor, as if someone had stated the opposite. Your example is great: $x_n=c\Rightarrow X_k=cN\delta_k$. This gives for Parseval's theorem $Nc^2=\frac{1}{N}N^2c^2\quad\checkmark$. So what argument don't you 'buy'?

Comment: @MattL. I meant *in contrast* to the fourier series or fourier integral. Which is why the versions of Parseval's theorem for those cases *dont't* have the equivalent of the $\frac{1}{N}$. Should have actually spelled that out, though ;-)